# Nvidia driver update: Access is denied in Device Manager

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card

I had an incident this morning where during a routine driver update on my work computer (Nvidia nvs 310, Windows 8.1), the Nvidia Geforce Experience tool uninstalled the old drivers, but couldn't install the new drivers, failing with a bland "Nvidia Installer Failed" error.

I tried a couple of things after that:

1. Finished installing Windows Updates: didn't fix it.
2. used Display Driver Uninstaller to fully uninstall the old drivers: didn't fix it.
3. Tried to install the Dell display drivers from the Dell support site for my machine: Didn't fix it.
4. Tried using the device administrator instead of my personal user account from AD: didn't fix it.
5. Updated the GPU BIOS: Didn't fix it.
6. Attempted to install through Device Manager: Didn't fix it, but it did tell me a deeper error with "Access Is Denied".

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling for this issue, I found an article from the Microsoft support site at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/access-denied-when-i-try-to-update-a-driver-in/9cb46cac-6723-450b-82df-b185a00a97eb which stated the following:

> I have had 4 users install MalwareBytes from https://www.malwarebytes.org/, run a scan, clean, reboot and then go through Device Manager again to manually update the driver to the existing one installed.

This is what I did in the end: install MalwareBytes, run a scan, clean (didn't find anything, but still), reboot and then install the Dell latest supported driver through Device Manager using the .inf file in the extracted folder. This ended up installing without any issues.

Why this worked is beyond my understanding. My best guess is that MalwareBytes fixed the permissions as part of the scan.